# WWW is not ready downloading yet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to  get some json  from a web service but i get this error when I try to use result.text it rises the error "WWW is not ready downloading yet" if i don't try to use this variable, I dont get any error

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Boomlagoon.JSON;

public class ClassInfoScript : MonoBehaviour {

private IEnumerator coroutine;
public string name;
private bool showInfo = false;
//esta variable es para controlar que solo seconecte uan vez al entrar en un collider
private bool connected = false;
private bool isClass = false;
private bool isDependency = false;
private bool isOffice= false;
public GUIStyle myStyle;
public GUIStyle labelStyle;
enum Types{classroom, dependency, office};


void Start(){

}
void OnGUI() {
    if (showInfo) {
        GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width * 0.02f, Screen.height * 0.02f, Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height * 0.75f), "", myStyle);
        WWW result = null;
        if (isClass) {
            if(!connected){
                result = get ("http://localhost/ws/get/clase/D1");

            }
            //I get the error here when I try to use result.text
            JSONObject jo = JSONObject.Parse(result.text);
        connected = true;
    }
}
//obtener el nombre
public void setName(string value){
    name = value;
}
//cambiar el nombre
public string getName(){
    return name;
}
//cambiar el  valor de showInfo
public void changeInfoState(){
    showInfo = !showInfo;
}
public void changeClass(){
    isClass = !isClass;
}
public void changeDependency(){
    isDependency = !isDependency;
}
public void changeOffice(){
    showInfo = !showInfo;
}
public WWW get(string url){
    WWW w = new WWW (url);
    StartCoroutine(AskWebservice(w));
    return w;
}

IEnumerator AskWebservice(WWW w){
    Debug.Log ("Coroutine started");
    yield return w;
    if (w.error == null){
        Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + w.text);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ w.error);
    }    

}

}
```

Now My onGui function is like this

```
void OnGUI() {
    if (showInfo) {
        GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width * 0.02f, Screen.height * 0.02f, Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height * 0.75f), "", myStyle);
        WWW result = null;
        JSONObject jo = null;

        if (isClass) {
            if(!connected){
                string url = "http://localhost/ws/get/clase/"+getName();
                StartCoroutine(HandleWWWRequest(url, (www) => {
                    jo = JSONObject.Parse(www.text);
                    Debug.Log(jo.GetString("info"));
                    connected = true;
                }));
            }
            GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width * 0.03f, Screen.height * 0.04f, Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height * 0.75f), jo.GetString("nombre"), labelStyle);
            GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width * 0.03f, Screen.height * 0.15f, Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height * 0.75f), jo.GetString("info"), labelStyle);

        } else if (isDependency) {
            /*coroutine = AskWebservice ("dependencia", name, Types.dependency);
            if(!connected)
                StartCoroutine (coroutine);

            GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width * 0.03f, Screen.height * 0.04f, Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height * 0.75f), response [0], labelStyle);
            GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width * 0.03f, Screen.height * 0.15f, Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height * 0.75f), response [1], labelStyle);
            GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width * 0.03f, Screen.height * 0.20f, Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height * 0.75f), response [2], labelStyle);*/
        }
        connected = true;
    }
}
```

But in this two lines

```
GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width * 0.03f, Screen.height * 0.04f, Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height * 0.75f), jo.GetString("nombre"), labelStyle);
GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width * 0.03f, Screen.height * 0.15f, Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height * 0.75f), jo.GetString("info"), labelStyle);
```

i can't use the jsonobject fields in the labels, it are nulls and i have tried to store this fields in another variables and in a list but it doesn't work,how i can store the jsonobject fields to use it after i execute the coroutine??I nedd to use this filds in the labels.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Re your update to the question: move any code that needs to use the returned WWW data _inside_ the code block. In your case move the GUI.Label calls just under the "connected = true;" line.

Comment: This is the first thing I've tried but the values are not shown on the label,labels are empty

Comment: Ahhh... this is old school Unity UI. It needs to refresh itself each OnGUI update. So just store the text in an class instance field outside of OnGUI (info = jo.GetString("info") _inside_ the code block) then use that in the GUI.Label call once it's set (check for null or set it to empty string initially etc).

Comment: On a related note, use the new Unity UI system rather than the old one. It's an actual production level UI system rather than a quick and mostly dirty prototyping UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get` function is a non blocking call. StartCoroutine needs to be used with a yield, for example `yield return StartCoroutine(...)`, for your code to wait for the coroutine to finish. Because the WWW hasn't finished there is no result yet.

Try something like this:

```
IEnumerator HandleWWWRequest(string url, System.Action<WWW> onSuccess) {
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)) {
        onSuccess(www);
    } else {
        Debug.LogWarning("WWW request returned an error.");
    }
}

...

if (isClass) {
    if(!connected){
        string url = "http://localhost/ws/get/clase/D1";
        // Non-blocking... success handling code is passed as a lambda
        StartCoroutine(HandleWWWRequest(url, (www) => {
            JSONObject jo = JSONObject.Parse(www.text);
            connected = true;
        }));
    }
}
```

To keep the code clear I didn't include an onError callback but you you can easily add it.